# jquery dataTables - Sorting with range

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have this working example for sorting a table including column sorting.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e7g8u2sf/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#searchresults thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#searchresults thead' );
    $('#searchresults thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
        var title = $(this).text();
        // how to create 2 input fields to filter a range (e.g. filter rows where price ranges from 5 to 20)
        if (title == 'price') {
            // how can I do this ?
        }
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" />' );
        $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
                table
                    .column(i)
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
    var table = $('#searchresults').DataTable( {
        orderCellsTop: true,
        fixedHeader: true
    });
});
```

I am wondering how I can make a column sortable by a range.
In my example, I want to have 2 input fields ("from" and "to") for the "price" column to show only items in the table whose price is e.g. between 5 and 20.

Answer (score 0):

you have made a parenthesis error

`if ( (( isNaN( min_id ) && isNaN( max_id ) ) ||`
             `( isNaN( min_id ) && id <= max_id ) ||`
            `( min_id <= id   && isNaN( max_id ) ) ||`
            `( min_id <= id   && id <= max_id )) &&`
             `(( isNaN( min_price ) && isNaN( max_price ) ) ||`
             `( isNaN( min_price ) && price <= max_price ) ||`
             `( min_price <= price   && isNaN( max_price ) ) ||`
            `( min_price <= price   && price <= max_price ))`
           `)`
Also You need to change id => min_vol,min_price && max_vol,max_price

Comment: Thank you, Yusuf. I edited the typo in my jsfiddle and fixing the parenthesis error made my example work. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1wqjhz7g/1/)

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(

    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {

        var min_id = parseInt( $('#min_id').val(), 10 );
        var max_id = parseInt( $('#max_id').val(), 10 );
        var id = parseFloat( data[0] ) || 0; // use data for the id column

        var min_price = parseInt( $('#min_price').val(), 10 );
        var max_price = parseInt( $('#max_price').val(), 10 );
        var price = parseFloat( data[1] ) || 0;

    var title = $('#title').val();
        var title_data = data[2] || '';
        
        if (
               (
                ( isNaN( min_id ) && isNaN( max_id ) ) ||
                ( isNaN( min_id ) && id <= max_id ) ||
                ( min_id <= id   && isNaN( max_id ) ) ||
                ( min_id <= id   && id <= max_id )
               )
            && (
                ( isNaN( min_price ) && isNaN( max_price ) ) ||
                ( isNaN( min_price ) && price <= max_price ) ||
                ( min_price <= price   && isNaN( max_price ) ) ||
                ( min_price <= price   && price <= max_price )
               )
            && (
                ( title == '' ) ||
                ( title != '' && title_data.toLowerCase().includes(title.toLowerCase()) )
               )               
            )
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#searchresults').DataTable( {
        orderCellsTop: true,
        fixedHeader: true,
        paging: false,
        language: {
                url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/German.json'
        }
    });   

    // Event listeners to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
    $('#min_id, #max_id').keyup( function() {
        table.draw();
    } );
    $('#min_price, #max_price').keyup( function() {
        table.draw();
    } );
    $('#title').keyup( function() {
        table.draw();
    } );    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>

<table class="datatable" id="searchresults">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>title</th>
  </tr>
   <tr role="row">
     <th>
       <div style="white-space:nowrap;">
         <input type="text" id="min_id" name="min_id" size="3" placeholder="from">
         <input type="text" id="max_id" name="max_id" size="3" placeholder="to">
       </div>
     </th>
     <th>
       <div style="white-space:nowrap;">
         <input type="text" id="min_price" name="min_price" size="3" placeholder="from">
         <input type="text" id="max_price" name="max_price" size="3" placeholder="to">
       </div>
     </th>   
     <th>       
       <input type="text" id="title" name="title" size="10">
     </th>      
   </tr>  
 </thead> 
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>candies</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>book</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>mouse</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>keyboard</td>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>red wine</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>white wine</td>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>red wine</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>49</td>
    <td>red wine</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>white wine</td>
  </tr>   
 </tbody>
</table>
```

If the results table got hundreds of records there is a light delay while typing. I am trying to make this a bit smoother.